# Log source IPs of all incoming packets

Tags: iptables

How does one log the IP addresses of all machines that send packets or connect to the server?  Also, how can one block IPs which are involved in a DDoS and are flooding the server with packets?

Comment: Centos 6 64 bit.

Comment: this look like a work for fail2ban

Answer (score 1):

A few cautious words up-front: [Defending against a DDoS attack is difficult and generally requires the help of your ISP](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/114/89792).  Iptables alone won't protect you and might even be harmful.  I don't think you really want do what you are asking for.

- DDoS are meant to cause denial of service by overloading your system.  Logging packets will increase the load of your system.  So you'd be doing the attackers a favor.
- The source of an IP address is easily spoofable.  Imagine you are connected to your server via ssh and an attacker learns your laptop's IP address.  It is very very easy to send packets looking like they came from any given IP, in this example that of your laptop.  Your server will respond by blocking your IP address, effectively locking you out.  This technique allows the attacker have any IP address blocked by server.  Again, you are doing the attacker a favor and make their job a lot simpler.

With that out of the way:

Log every individual IP address to your syslog (limit to 1 entry per IP and hour):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 \! -i lo                 \
  -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name "IP_SOURCES" \
               --hashlimit-mode srcip        \
               --hashlimit-burst 1           \
               --hashlimit-upto 1/hour       \
  -j LOG
```

Replace `iptables` with `ip6tables` to do the same for IPv6 packets.

Blocking an IP would work in a similar way, just throw the `conntrack` module into the above rule, match `NEW` connections and set the jump target to `DROP`.  But again, I really think you'd do yourself a disservice if you were to actually do this.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 \! -i lo                 \
  -m conntrack --ctstate NEW                 \
  -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name "RATE_LIMIT" \
               --hashlimit-mode srcip        \
               --hashlimit-burst 20          \
               --hashlimit-above 1/min       \
  -j DROP
```

This will allow 20 connection attempts per minute, dropping all other connection attempts.  Packets of established connections can still pass through unharmed.

As noted in the comments, `fail2ban` might be a good solution to block unwanted traffic.  It won't help you if the attackers are generating a SYN-flood, or are using IPv6, but it will be useful e.g. if the attackers are trying to brute-force their way into your ssh or smtp server with a "normal" IPv4 connection.

Comment: @roaima Thanks, I forgot to mention it. I added a paragraph on fail2ban.